# Using PHP's $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] under an open_basedir restriction

Tags: php, document-root

I've spent the past few months building a website on localhost. Throughout the site, instead of using relative paths, I used `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` to access the root of my server so I could reference files from there. However, I just decided to upload my site to 000webhost. As I soon found out, and for those of you who use them, you are probably aware, that their server root is different than your actual directory in which you upload your files. I believe it's virtual hosting... anyway, my `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` now throws errors along the lines of this on the site:

> Warning: include_once() [function.include-once]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/local/apache/htdocs/mypath) is not within the allowed path(s)

Every other site I looked at said that you should just replace `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` with the home directory provided to you by 000webhost. However, if I want to change hosting services in the future, I'm screwed. Is there any way to use `$_SERVER` to access a set virtual directory or use htaccess or something to make my code work? I tried using DocumentRoot in a htaccess file in my root directory, but it threw a 404 error when trying to access the page.

Answer (score 4):

I would never recommend using `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. For example, it is useless if you ever want to run scripts via the command line or cron.

I would instead, set the `include_path` via one of your scripts. Something that is included in every page (like some sort of config or bootstrap script).

For example, say you have `config.php` in your app's root directory (could be doc root but it's not important) that is included on every page

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    __DIR__, // this is the directory of this file, config.php
    get_include_path()
)));
```

Then, you can safely use relative paths from this location in your `include` / `require` statements

```
include 'foo.php';         // APP_ROOT/foo.php
include 'somedir/bar.php'; // APP_ROOT/somedir/bar.php
```

When setting the include path, it doesn't really matter where the script resides, just construct the appropriate path. Say `config.php` lived in `APP_ROOT/configs/config.php`, the include path would be

```
realpath(__DIR__ . '/..') // realpath just resolves the path traversal
```

Comment: @Nickersoft `I've spent the past few months building a website on localhost`: This means the website was not fully active before the host switch, that in turn means you do have time to implement this solution. Do it when the tide is low, rather than feeling so desperate again later when you have customers.

Comment: Haha I don't have customers yet... I'm just hoping to launch soon is all.

Answer (score -1):

Decided to go with the following method:

http://www.000webhost.com/forum/customer-assistance/4857-document_root-environment-variable.html

Works!